# how to pass the result set to another oracle sql query in Python

Tags: python, python-oracledb

I have the below code and its working fine. i am trying to figure out a way to pass the the result directly to the query instead of in_clause  variable.

I tried the below code but its failing with `DPY-3002: Python value of type "tuple" is not supported`

```
testQuery="select * from TRX_HDR where hdr_id in (:hdr_ids)"
cursor.execute(testQuery, {'hdr_ids': results})
```

Complete code

````
query = "SELECT column_name FROM your_table WHERE your_condition"
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
ord_ids = [result[0] for result in results]

# Constructing the IN clause for the second query
in_clause = ', '.join(map(str, ord_ids))


testQuery = f"SELECT * FROM TRX_HDR WHERE hdr_id IN ({in_clause})"
cursor.execute(testQuery)
second_query_results = cursor.fetchall()```
````

Comment: I appreciate that this might be a minimal example for something bigger, but is there a reason that you don't just combine the queries? It'd be much more efficient than pulling it through a python layer